# Start Translucent Activity Periodically Without Disrupting Current Activity

Tags: android

I have a translucent activity which I want to start every minute after initially pressing a button. This activity contains a line of text which I just want displayed even if the user has closed the app, without interrupting the user's current activity (which should be visible in the background. So far, I can get the activity to start, but it stops the current activity and the background is another activity from my own application.
Below is the alarm class I created:

```
public void startAlarm(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (1000 * 60),
                pendingIntent);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (1000 * 60),
                pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Now my broadcast receiver class:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Start service
    Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    context.startService(service);

    // Schedule next alarm
    alarm.startAlarm(context);
}
```

And now the service which starts the activity:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Start ad activity
    Intent activity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    activity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(activity);

    stopSelf();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Here is my manifest.xml showing the activity in question:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FullTransparent" />
```

And the style that I applied:

```
<style name="Theme.FullTransparent" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you just want to display a bit of text over whatever activity is up? Why can't you just use a Toast?

Comment: *(showing) translucent activity ... without interrupting the user's current activity* not possible

Comment: Remove this activity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: @Dportology i intend to add an image as well

Comment: @Selvin how about pausing the current activity while displaying mine then?

Comment: @Jai when i do the service fails

Comment: @StephNoutsa : what did you mean by service fails ? Isn't it opening new activity?

Comment: @Jai no...The application stops entirely. I get an ANR